# Java Stack Sort Symbol Balancing

Tags: java, sorting, stack

The program I am writing has to read a loaded text document and check to see if all the (, [, and { are balanced as well as ignoring anything in between "" and after //.  What I have so far checks to see if the first three symbols are all balanced, but I am having trouble with checking the line numbers on which the first occurrence happens.  I know that I have to write that if the next symbol is a " or //, I ignore that line or until I hit the next ", but I am unsure of the correct syntax.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is what I have so far:

```
    import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;

public class Sorting extends JFrame implements ActionListener{



    private Stack<Character> symbolStack;



    JTextArea opentextArea;
    JTextArea placetextArea;
    JMenuItem open;
    final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Sorting gui = new Sorting();




    }




    public Sorting()
     {




        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        setTitle("Stack Sort");

        JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menuItems = new JMenu("File");
        open = new JMenuItem("Open");
        open.addActionListener(this);
        JMenuItem reset = new JMenuItem("Reset");


        reset.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
                    {
                        opentextArea.setText("");
                        placetextArea.setText("");
                    }   
                }
            );

        menuItems.add(open);
        menuItems.add(reset);

        menuBar.add(menuItems);
        setJMenuBar(menuBar);
        opentextArea = new JTextArea();
        placetextArea = new JTextArea();
        add(opentextArea);
        add(placetextArea);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   pack();
   setVisible(true);


     }




    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
        {

            File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
            FileInputStream is = null;
            try
            {
                is = new FileInputStream(file);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
            }


            byte [] nextChar = new byte[2];

            try
            {

                int value = is.read(nextChar);
                int num = 1;
                opentextArea.append(num + ":" );


                while (value != -1)
                {
                    String newString = new String(nextChar);
                    if (nextChar[0] == '\n' || nextChar[0] == '\r')
                    {
                        num++;
                        opentextArea.append(newString + num + ":" );

                    }
                    else 
                        opentextArea.append(newString);


                    value = is.read(nextChar);

                }


            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e.toString());
            }


            Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
            String s = opentextArea.getText();
            int index = 0;
            int numline = 1;
            while(index < s.length()) {
                char ch = s.charAt(index);
                if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                    {
                        numline++;
                        index++;
                    }
                else
                if(ch == '{' || ch == '[' || ch == '(')
                    {
                        stack.push(ch);
                        index++;
                    } 
                else {
                    if(stack.empty()) 
                    {
                        index++;
                        //placetextArea.append("No balance characters found.");
                        continue;
                    }

                    char ch1 = stack.pop();

                    if(ch1 == '{' && ch == '}' || ch1 == '[' && ch == ']' || ch1 == '(' && ch == ')') 
                    {
                        placetextArea.append(ch1 + " at line " +numline + " matches up with " + ch + " at line " + numline + "\n");
                    } 
                    else
                        if(ch1 == '{' && ch != '}' || ch1 == '[' && ch != ']' || ch1 == '(' && ch != ')')
                        {
                            placetextArea.append("error unmatched " + ch1 + "at line " +numline);
                            break;
                        } 
                    }

                }






    }
}
}
```

Here is my edited code:

```
    Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<Character>();
        String s = opentextArea.getText();
        int index = 0;
        int numline = 1;
        while(index < s.length()) {
            char ch = s.charAt(index);
            if (ch == '\n' || ch == '\r')
                {
                    numline++;
                    index++;
                }
            else
            if(ch == '{' || ch == '[' || ch == '(')
                {
                    stack.push(ch);
                    index++;
                } 
            else {
                if(stack.empty()) 
                {
                    index++;
                    //placetextArea.append("No balance characters found.");
                    continue;
                }
                // pop an item from stack
                if(ch == '}' || ch == ']' || ch == ')')
                {
                char ch1 = stack.pop();
                // check if it's a matching pair
                if(ch1 == '{' && ch == '}' || ch1 == '[' && ch == ']' || ch1 == '(' && ch == ')') 
                {
                    placetextArea.append(ch1 + " at line " +numline + " matches up with " + ch + " at line " + numline + "\n");
                } 
                else
                    if(ch1 == '{' && ch != '}' || ch1 == '[' && ch != ']' || ch1 == '(' && ch != ')')
                    {
                        placetextArea.append("error unmatched " + ch1 + "at line " +numline);
                        break;

                    } 
                }

            }






}
```

Comment: You don't have to edit your post in this manner. How capitalize and share knowledge if everybody do like that? Please cancel your last edit.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pop from the stack only when you encounter one of `)`, `}` or `]`. Then you check if the closing one matches with the opening. Also you need to define a behavior when it is unmatched: to push the opening back or to drop it. At the EOF you should check if the stack is empty. Otherwise you have something unbalanced.

Comment: Yes, you defined - you drop the popped brace on the floor. To see why you need to check at EOF if stack is empty consider this text (it is a full file content): `(`.

Comment: sorry, my prev statement on freeze was wrong. but anyway you should remove the existing `if(stack.empty()) {...}`. You need to check if the stack is empty when you encounter the closing symbol as it is also unbalanced if it has no matching opening symbol. And don't forget to bump the index (this is actual cause of freeze)